# A list of verbs that take only accusative objects

Tags: verb, grammatical-case

Does anybody have a full list of german verbs that take akkusativ object?
I have found a list fot dative but couldn't found for akkusativ.

Comment: There is nothing like a *full list of German verbs*, so there also can't be a subset for verbs that take akkusativ object. German is a living language. Some verbs become extinct (*volvieren, dünken, maledeien*) and some other verbs suddenly appear that never before was part of German *Wortschatz* (*barfen, dissen, zappen*). Not to forget verbs like *twittern, googeln, whatsappen*. So, the set of German verbs is changing all the time. You never will be able to get complete list of all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure why people always ask for *full* lists of verbs (do you have a *full* dictionary of German?) ...

One way to get *a* list is through the dictionary of verb valence, https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/verbvalenz. Select K<sub>akk</sub> (accusative complement) on the left and click "Search". This will give you a list of verbs for which a meaning exists in which the verb can be used with an accusative complement (~ object). (If you check "verbspezifische Suche", it will list each verb only once). By chosing specific sentence structures (Satzbaupläne) on the left, you can further narrow down your results, say, to verbs with a meaning where an accusative complement is required (for that, you would need to go through all entries that include K<sub>akk</sub> [where the K<sub>akk</sub> is not in parantheses because that indicates optionality]).

The dictionary dictionary of verb valence is not that comprehensive as yet but it may still be a starting point :).

Comment: Der erste Satz ist der wichtigste. Hier könntest du noch ergänzen, dass die meisten deutschen Verben ein Akkusativ-Objekt fordern. Das würde unterstreichen, dass es die "full list" hierfür nahezu nicht geben kann.